# What is wrong with this code for loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to test an example model `create` but it shows `Cannot GET /explorer/` with browsing `localhost:3001/explorer`:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

var Item = loopback.createModel(
  'Item',
  {
    description: 'string',
    completed: 'boolean'
  }
);

app.model(Item);
app.use('/api', loopback.rest());

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

app.listen(3001);
```

Comment: Your path dude.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 could you please explain more. Please. I am newbie to loopback.

Comment: The url you provided is not the one you are getting to . Is this route?

Comment: I got it from this tutorial https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-express-restify-hapi-loopback/

Answer (score 0):

It says here that you should put it before the app.listen(8080); so basically your code structure should look like this

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

//you add the items here like 
/* 
POST /Items
GET /Items
PUT /Items
PUT /Items/{id}
HEAD /Items/{id}
GET /Items/{id}
DELETE /Items/{id}
GET /Items/{id}/exists
GET /Items/count
GET /Items/findOne
POST /Items/update
*/
var Item = loopback.createModel(
'Item',
{
description: 'string',
completed: 'boolean'
}
);

app.model(Item);
app.use('/api', loopback.rest());

    app.start = function() {
// start the web server
return app.listen(function() {
app.emit('started');
var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
}
});
};
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I've tested, I don't understand the same result.